# Android Logcat regex with app tag and custom TAG

Tags: android, regex, logcat, android-logcat

I'm searching for a regex that I could se in Android Studio custom filter on logcat window. The window look like this : 
[image: filter window]

here is a log sample that I need to filter :

```
08-06 15:46:13.883  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#BADTAG﹕ process
08-06 15:46:13.883  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#BADTAG﹕ processUri
08-06 15:46:13.884  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#BADTAG﹕ About to create doc from InputStream
08-06 15:46:13.886  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#BADTAG﹕ Doc successfully created.
08-06 15:46:13.887  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#BADTAG﹕ About to merge doc into main doc.
08-06 15:46:13.887  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#XmlTools﹕ xmlDocumentToString
08-06 15:46:13.895  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#BADTAG﹕ Merge successful.
08-06 15:46:13.895  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#BADTAG﹕ Doc is a wrapper.
08-06 15:46:13.905  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#BADTAG﹕ processUri
08-06 15:46:13.905  27841-12352/not.to.me D/me#BADTAG﹕ begin
08-06 15:46:13.905  27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest D/me#MainActivity : so
```

I want to **keep line** with `tv.me.sdkapptest` that **not contain** `me#BADTAG` or `me#XmlTools`

As a result, only the last line should match. I'm already using this : `^((?!(#BADTAG)|(#XmlTools)).)+$` but is does not remove `not.to.me` lines.

Comment: Like `(?m)^(?:(?!me#BADTAG|me#XmlTools).)*$` or `(?m)^(?!.*(?:me#BADTAG|me#XmlTools))`?

Comment: @stribizhev that will keep `08-06 16:00:01.037      940-977/? I/ProcessStatsService﹕ Prepared write state in 0ms` which is not valid for me

Comment: But this line has no `me#BADTAG` or `me#XmlTools`.

Comment: yes but it did not contain `tv.me.sdkapptest`, I want to keep only this line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the regex I posted in the question is the one. The things is that I was misreading the filter pannel which have the log tag, log message and package name. In my case, the package name is `tv.me.app` and the regex should remove on  `me#BADTAG` or `me#XmlTools` in the tag log.

Here is the correct filter configuration
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?!.*(?:me#BADTAG|me#XmlTools))
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eC3gO3/2)

The regex means

- `^` - Beginning of a line
- `(?!.*(?:me#BADTAG|me#XmlTools))` - a negative look-ahead that fails the match if the line has `me#BADTAG` or `me#XmlTools` in it

As you found out, to only display the log entries pertaining to some package, this package name must be added to the **Package Name**  field in the Logcat Filter Dialog.

Comment: I can't find the relevant documentation, but it seems the `(?m)` might not be required.

Comment: I don't know why but both regex (java style and regular) didn't show any matching lines

Comment: What if you try `^(?=.*tv[.]me[.]sdkapptest)(?!.*(?:me#BADTAG|me#XmlTools))`?

Comment: Ok I've checked and the window I've posted in the question is in fact explicite. So `(?!.*(?:me#BADTAG|me#XmlTools))` did the work, but I need to specify in the Package Name tv.me.sdkapptest

Comment: So, if you type `27841-12352/tv.me.sdkapptest` or `tv.me.sdkapptest` do you finally get expected results?

Comment: By using this yes, https://www.dropbox.com/s/wo7vl50molqdh6w/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-08-07%2009.37.36.png?dl=0 I will post a new answer if you are ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85389/discussion-between-stribizhev-and-hugo-gresse).